# Manage Sort options in OS X Photos App

Tags: macos, photos, sort

OSX 10.10.3 has been just released and I immediately migrated my iPhoto library to Photos.

More or less there's everything I'm used to in iPhoto but Apple's removed a useful function: I can't reverse the order by date of an album! I mean, on iPhoto I have some smart album sorted with recent photos on top and older bottom but, by default it would be otherwise. In iPhoto there was a menu voice to set it but in Photos, actually, there isn't.

I tried searching album source file (as a .plist) to modify but I can't find it.

Has some one any idea on how to manage sort options on new Yosemite's Photos?

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing, but can't find it either. As you stated, that old menu item in iPhoto doesn't exist in the new photos app, and does not seem to exist anywhere else in the program. Very frustrating. I always keep new photos on top and can't reorder the photos in descending order anymore. Will keep looking...

Comment: Could you explain which view you are using when you want to sort photos? Is it under "Photos" or "Shared" or "Albums" or "Projects"?

Comment: Initially, in Photos package there were lot of files corresponding to all albums and I tried to modify their sort options from those files but, reopening Photos nothing change so I tried repairing library but, after that, all those files disappeared so, probably, were old files from iPhoto...     I want to sort smart albums in albums section...but having the possibility to modify all wouldn't be bad!

Comment: I don't understand Apple: they claim to implement software so that they provide what most people want. I'm sure that most people are interested in the latest photos and not into the oldest photos! Sorting by date in ascending order just does not make sense if you have photos over 20 years...

Comment: That's it! I'm using Photos and it's very functional, I like it! But that little lack is giant for me...

Answer (score 2):

I sort by date by selecting Albums at the top of Photos window.

Then use the View menu to check **Keep Sorted By Date**

There isn't any way to reverse that currently and I don't see any indication that they'll do anything other than tell you to scroll to the bottom to see the other ordering.

Comment: Ye, I saw it but it's not what I need...

Comment: @Matte.Car I know - it's just not there. Apple ruthlessly cut functions and features and UI from iPhotos and Aperture. My uneducated guess is that's the design intent and not something that will change over time. I think Photos will remain lean, mean, basics and leave space for custom apps to fill in. I can't decide yet if I can live within Photos or if it will simply be step one before photos end up in the main database for me to exert more fine grained control over.

Comment: I'm not happy too from this forced migration but I did it immediately because, soon or later, everybody have to do that. And I agree that it will remain very basic waiting for 3rd party plugins integration. My hope is that someone find a way to modify sort options, even working with hidden files as .plist or working with database, I tried but I couldn't...